# How to turn off iPhone 5 Edge/GPRS?

Tags: iphone

My friend has just got an iPhone 5 for the first time and she is having problem with turning off the EDGE/GPRS connection.

She would turn off 3G connection in the `setting` but there seems to be nowhere to turn off EDGE or GPRS.

Comment: Why do you want to turn off EDGE ?

Comment: You can turn off Cellular Data in Settings > General Cellular > Cellular Data. How did she turn off *just* the 3G connection?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler The reason is to control when to go online, e.g. prefer to logged in facebook with wifi only

Comment: When wifi is available. iPhone will only use the Wifi, not the cellular network.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I mean she doesn't want to be still logged in facebook when she goes outside where there's no wifi

Comment: Then do what bassplayer7 suggested :  turn off Cellular Data in Settings > General Cellular > Cellular Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to :

- Settings
- General
- Cellular

Set cellular data to OFF